# Datadog cannot find check in "catalog" when implementing integration

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, datadog

I've been trying to implement a Datadog integration, more specifically Airflow's. I've been following this [piece of documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/airflow/?tabs=containerized) using the containerized approach (I've tried using pod annotations and adding the confd parameters to the agent's Helm values). I've only made advances when adding the `airflow.yaml` config to the `confd` sectrion of the cluster agent. However, I get stuck when I try to validate the integration as specified in the documentation by running `datadog-cluster-agent status`. Under the "Running Checks" section, I can see the following:

```
airflow
-------
  Core Check Loader:
    Check airflow not found in Catalog
```

On top of being extremely generic, this error message mentions a "Catalog" that is not referenced anywhere else in the DD documentation. It doesn't tell me or give me any hints on what could possibly wrong with the integration. Anyone had the same problem and knows how to solve it or at least how can I get more info/details/verbosity to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add [`cluster_check: true`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/cluster_agent/clusterchecks/?tab=helm#configuration-from-configuration-files) to your `airflow.yaml` `confd` configuration.